# Error: Unexpected request: POST http://server:80/api/metrics No more request expected

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Hi I have a found several related questions and tried to mimic the solutions that worked for these questions but I am confused why I get this error when I set up my expectation correctly.

My test

```
describe("Controller", function () {
var scope, SearchCtrl, httpBackend, searchSerivce;

//load the controller"s module
beforeEach(module("myApp"));

beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
        httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
    });
});

//initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {

    // create a new child scope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();


    scope.SearchService = $injector.get("SearchService");

    //create a new instance of basic search controller
    SearchCtrl = $controller("BasicSearchCtrl", { $scope: scope });


}));


//check the search after setting the same text
it("setting some text content in search to check it is updated in searchservice basicSearch", function () {

    scope.search = "test";

    httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://server:80/api/metrics').respond(200);

    scope.$digest();

    expect(scope.SearchService.basicSearch).toBe("test");

});
```

As you can see I'm setting up the expectation for this metrics page with the following line

```
httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://server:80/api/metrics').respond(200);
```

I've also tried

```
    httpBackend.expectGET('http://server:80/api/metrics');
    httpBackend.whenGET('http://server:80/api/metrics').respond(200);
```

And

```
    httpBackend.expectGET('api/metrics');
    httpBackend.whenGET('api/metrics').respond(200);
```

And

```
    httpBackend.expectGET('/api/metrics');
    httpBackend.whenGET('/api/metrics').respond(200);
```

But they all give me this error

```
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://server:80/api/metrics
No more request expected
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

*Update*

Solution...it was a POST not get so

```
    //set up an expectation and response for this POST
    httpBackend.expectPOST('http://server:80/api/metrics').respond(200);
```

worked

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! Would you please add your solution as the answer and mark it so the question shows as answered?